# Why a value of false for IsSuccessStatusCode when the request appears successful?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WPF client using an ASP.NET Web API 2 as a central server. In the Web API, I have this action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> persons;
    try
    {
        persons = Db.People.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ExceptionResult(ex, this);
    }
    return Ok(persons);
}
```

When I step through this method, it exits on `return Ok(persons);`, and the debug I am following returns to the WPF client, where the response has `IsSuccessStatusCode == false`, with a status of "500 Internal Server Error" and nothing anywhere in the response explaining why?

I call this action with a generic method:

```
People = await Rest.PostAsync<IEnumerable<Person>>("/api/Persons");
...
public async Task<TReturn> PostAsync<TReturn>(string resource)
{
    var exMsg = $"Post request failed to get resource: '{resource}' from '{Client.BaseAddress}'.";
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync(resource, null);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Logger.Error(exMsg);
            RaiseException(response, exMsg);
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TReturn>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex.GetType() != typeof(RestClientException))
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, exMsg);
        throw;
    }
}
```

I don't use the ugly, blanket `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` because I've been lead to believe it causes information in the response to be lost.

This was still working, an hour ago, with no code changes except columns in a `DataGrid`, and maybe somehow, the fact that I changed data in the database, but not any of the data model components in the solution. Only data values, and then sure the `ToList()` in the action method would pull any data gremlins out of the woodwork.

I can only figure the HTTP 500 happens between the controller and the client, and I'm asking what could be wrong, and how can I diagnose it?

Comment: Why do u use Post not a Get ?

Comment: @aguetat Some time ago I learnt. for some good reasons I don't recall, that a Post was more secure for Ajax. In MVC, the `JsonResult` class even has a `JsonRequestBehavior` property that defaults to `DenyGet`, expecting almost all requests expecting JSON responses to fail if they are GETs, and you don't override that default with 'AllowGet'

Comment: U must to change the name of your action, when you call it "Get" the framework will consider it like a Get action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out stupid RestSharp was complaining that it "couldn't instantiate an interface" when I gave the type parameter of my return value as `IEnumerable<T>`. Changed it to `List<T>` and it worked. Then I dropped the useless library in favour of a pure and clean `HttpClient`, which can deserialize its response content to an "interface type".

Answer (score 0):

If it is running fine to the "return OK" line, and there are "persons" populated, then I would expect that the problem lies with serializing the Person object.
Does it have properties that reference other "Person" entities that could create an infinite loop for example?

If I could, I would create another endpoint which I can call with a Get request, and make the request using a browser so that I see the error response fairly easily.